# How to pass multiple pipelines while reindex

Tags: elasticsearch

Not able to pass multiple pipelines while reindexing

When i pass two pipelines in reindex body, i am getting below exception

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
                "reason": "[7:17] [dest] pipeline doesn't support values of type: START_ARRAY"
            }
        ],
        "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
        "reason": "[7:17] [reindex] failed to parse field [dest]",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
            "reason": "[7:17] [dest] pipeline doesn't support values of type: START_ARRAY"
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

```
{
  "source": {
    "index": "elastic_v1"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "elastic_v2",
    "pipeline": ["coram_count_script_pipeline","counsel_nested_split_foreach_pipeline"]
  }
}
```

Is their any work around for this or we need to reindex multiple times

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I suggest doing is to leverage the [`pipeline` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/pipeline-processor.html). You'd need to create another pipeline that delegates the work to your two existing pipelines and then reference that third pipeline in your reindex call.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/reindexing-pipeline
{
  "description" : "reindexing pipeline",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "pipeline" : {
        "name": "coram_count_script_pipeline"
      }
    },
    {
      "pipeline" : {
        "name": "counsel_nested_split_foreach_pipeline"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then your reindex call would look like this:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "elastic_v1"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "elastic_v2",
    "pipeline": "reindexing-pipeline"
  }
}
```